# Unable to display NO DATA message when data does not exist in the table

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am displaying table data using NgTableParams in angularjs. I was trying to show NO DATA EXISTS in the table when the data is not available or length is zero, but my code doesn't seems to work.

Demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/nEbjQE1NQW7VF8dlZvyy?p=preview

sample code:

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" class="table" show-filter="true">
   <tbody ng-repeat="user in $data">
    <tr ng-show="$data.length > 0"> 
          <td title="'Name'" filter="{ name: 'text'}" sortable="'name'">
       {{user.name}}</td>
      <td title="'Age'" filter="{ age: 'number'}" sortable="'age'">
        {{user.age}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-show="$data.length === 0"> 
          <td title="'Name'" filter="{ name: 'text'}" sortable="'name'">
      NO DATA FOUND</td>
      <td title="'Age'" filter="{ age: 'number'}" sortable="'age'">
        </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
```

js code:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, NgTableParams) {

  $scope.data1 = [];
console.log(" $scope.data1 length " +  $scope.data1.length);
$scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({}, { dataset: $scope.data1});  
});
```

Tried as below too , but it is not displaying the table header and filter for the columns..
Demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/XAOO5tPALVOkQW9hhJCs?p=preview:

```
 <tbody ng-show="!$data.length">
      <tr> 
          <td>
             NO DATA FOUND
          </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>

   <tbody ng-repeat="user in $data">
    <tr ng-show="$data.length > 0"> 
....
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here

The first one is that your `ng-repeat` directive is in your `tbody` this will cause your table body to be rendered for every single element in your array.

The second one is that your `"NO DATA FOUND"` message is inside of your `ng-repeat` block, no element will be rendered if `$data` is empty.

The solution would be to move the `ng-repeat` from your `tbody` to the actual element that you want to repeat for every item in your array, in this case, the `tr` that contains the data to be displayed.

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" class="table" show-filter="true">
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="user in $data" ng-show="$data.length > 0"> 
      <td title="'Name'" filter="{ name: 'text'}" sortable="'name'">
        {{user.name}}</td>
      <td title="'Age'" filter="{ age: 'number'}" sortable="'age'">
        {{user.age}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-show="$data.length === 0"> 
      <td title="'Name'" filter="{ name: 'text'}" sortable="'name'">
        NO DATA FOUND</td>
      <td title="'Age'" filter="{ age: 'number'}" sortable="'age'"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: But when i remove ng-repeat from tbody my other functionality is breaking ,Please find the demo http://next.plnkr.co/edit/rxprM10fZQTds5m4 . When i click on the image on each row (in the demo link) it has to expand and show more details for that row which is breaking when removed ng-repeat from tbody and place  in tr .

Comment: If you want to use the `ng-repeat` data for other rows you need to use `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` for this purpose, [i've just updated your demo](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/tQySVXcW77kfBxZv) with this approach

Comment: The same is not working for the expanded rows when the data is not available when clicked on the image present on first column. Demo :http://next.plnkr.co/edit/OeWl5kWNj1UfmNHv . Any inputs?

Comment: In your last Demo you've used `ng-repeat` with `ng-repeat-end`, as I said before, you need to use `ng-repeat-start` with `ng-repeat-end`, [Updated Demo](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/gsTufVfKp6FfF7TU)